# Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I trying to recover a mysql dump backup file but I keep on getting this error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the 
database.
Executing:
INSERT INTO `banco_distribuido`.`account` (`name`, `senha`, `accountNum`, 
`balance`, `funcionario`) VALUES ('Daniel', '1234', '1111', '1500', '1');

ERROR 3098: 3098: The table does not comply with the requirements by an 
external plugin.
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `banco_distribuido`.`account` (`name`, `senha`, `accountNum`, 
`balance`, `funcionario`) VALUES ('Daniel', '1234', '1111', '1500', '1')
```

What is this external plugin? Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to check the MySQL error log to see what the real database level error is.

Comment: Check if you have any tables without primary keys

Answer (score 0):

Probably should add a primary key to the table